# Not able to run single user single iteration load test in azure pipelines

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines, performance-testing, load-testing, taurus

I am trying to execute load test in azure pipelines. In my jmeter script when I mention single user and  test duration of particular time then in pipelines test run executes exactly for same time. But when I disable Duration and  thread group I mention as 1 user and  1 loop count, then test does not run for 1 loop. It continues running till build timeout. What could be the reason and what changes I should do in script so that script will run for exactly 1 loop in pipelines

Comment: Can you share your pipeline code?